# Counting distinct values in a field of a table stored in pgdb

Tags: vb.net

I need to calculate total count of distinct values of a field . That field contains many duplicate values also. The table which contains that field is stored in pgdb.
I want things done in vb .net. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArcObjects, you would do this by [IDataStatistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000182000000)  and  [IStatisticsResults](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0042000001pt000000)

[A 9.3 Example is here.](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/esriGeoDatabase/DataStatistics_Example.htm)

If you are using a personal geodatabase (which uses MS Access), you could use ADO and do a `SELECT DISTINCT <fieldname> FROM <TableName>` You can search SO for this info: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+votes%3A5+ADO+SELECT+DISTINCT

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant' to type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IEnumVariantSimple'. Above error is showing when i use the code from 9.3 example.enumVar = CType(dataStats.UniqueValues, IEnumVariantSimple) .However i did it using Hashset.Thanks Jay for help.

Comment: Dim datastats As IDataStatistics
        datastats = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.DataStatisticsClass
        datastats.Field = "IPID"
        datastats.Cursor = pCursor Dim enumerator As IEnumerator  enumerator = datastats.UniqueValues
        enumerator.Reset()
        Do While (enumerator.MoveNext())

            Dim myobject As Object
            myobject = enumerator.Current
            i = i + 1

        Loop